# keras - TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python, numpy, keras

I was trying to test a network, but seem to get an annoying error, which I am not quite sure I understand.

```
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation, Lambda, Reshape,Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv1D,Conv2D,MaxPooling2D, MaxPooling1D, Reshape
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras import backend as K
from keras.callbacks import ReduceLROnPlateau
from keras.callbacks import CSVLogger
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from keras.layers.merge import Concatenate
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
import random
import numpy as np


window_height = 8
filter_size=window_height
pooling_size = 28
stride_step = 2


def fws():


    np.random.seed(100)
    input = Input(5,window_height,1)
    shared_conv = Conv2D(filters = 1, kernel_size = (0,window_height,1))
    output = shared_conv(input)
    print output.shape


fws()
```

Error message:

```
File "experiment.py", line 34, in <module>
   fws()
 File "experiment.py", line 29, in fws
   input = Input(5,window_height,1)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 1426, in Input
   input_tensor=tensor)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 87, in wrapper
   return func(*args, **kwargs)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 1321, in __init__
   batch_input_shape = tuple(batch_input_shape)
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Why am i getting this error?

I am in the network trying to use shared convolution layer, which the code states,
and for test purposes want to see what the output became?..

Answer (score 24, accepted):

your line:

```
input = Input(5,window_height,1)
```

is giving this error.
compare this with an example from keras: 
https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/

```
inputs = Input(shape=(784,))
```

the `Input` object is expecting an iterable for `shape` but you passed it an `int`. In the example you can see how they get around that for a 1 dimensional input.

EDIT:
I don't know why this is a popular answer - if you're getting this error because you're following bad example code somewhere, be sure to raise that with whatever source you're getting it from.

Comment: W/o your help I would never ever find this one! MegaTanks!