# Tensorflow: Logits and labels must have the same first dimension

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I'm new to machine learning in TF. I have this dataset which I generated and exported into a .csv file. It is here: [tftest.csv](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stockfish8/PolySolver/master/tftest.csv).

The 'distributions' column corresponds to a unique system of equations which I have tried to condense down into a series of digits in SageMath. The 'probs' column correspond to whether one should mutiply a given equation by a given monomial of the equation, based on the row and column it is located in. The above is just for overview and is not related to my actual question.

Anyways, here's my code. I've tried to explain it as best as I can with annotations.

```html
import csv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as keras

distribution_train = []
probs_train = []
# x_train = []
# y_train = []

with open('tftest.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')

    for row in csv_reader:
        distribution_train.append(row[0])
        probs_train.append(row[1])

'''
Get rid of the titles in the csv file
'''
distribution_train.pop(0)
probs_train.pop(0)

'''
For some reason everything in my csv file is stored as strings.
The below function is to convert it into floats so that TF can work with it.
'''
def num_converter_flatten(csv_list):
    f = []
    for j in range(len(csv_list)):
        append_this = []
        for i in csv_list[j]:
            if i == '1' or i == '2' or i == '3' or i == '4' or i == '5' or i == '6' or i == '7' or i == '8' or i =='9' or i =='0':
                append_this.append(float(i))
        f.append((append_this))

    return f

x_train = num_converter_flatten(distribution_train)
y_train = num_converter_flatten(probs_train)

x_train = tf.keras.utils.normalize(x_train, axis=1)
y_train = tf.keras.utils.normalize(y_train, axis=1)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu))

'''
I'm making the final layer 80 because I want TF to output the size of the
'probs' list in the csv file
'''

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(80, activation=tf.nn.softmax))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5)
```

However, when I run my code, I get the following error.

```html
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [32,80] and labels shape [2560]
 [[{{node loss/output_1_loss/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits}} = SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits[T=DT_FLOAT, Tlabels=DT_INT64, _class=["loc:@train...s_grad/mul"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](loss/output_1_loss/Log, loss/output_1_loss/Cast)]]
```

I searched online for this error, but I can't seem to understand why it's cropping up. Can anyone help me understand what's wrong with my code? If there are any questions as well, please leave a comment and I'll do my best to answer them.

Comment: You're missing a reshape somewhere, as 32x80=2560. Is 32 your batch size?

Comment: Yes, it's unspecified and I checked the documentation, it defaults to 32.

Comment: Yes, so your model is missing a reshape. Try adding model.add(Reshape((-1))) at the last layer

Comment: Hi, reshape is not defined. However, I added your command and with model.add(y_train.reshape((-1))) and I got the following error: 'TypeError: The added layer must be an instance of class Layer. Found: [0.         0.         0.17407766 ... 0.         0.19611614 0.19611614]'

Comment: Yes, you should use tf.keras.layers.Reshape((-1))

Comment: Are you suggesting model.add(tf.keras.layers.Reshape((-1)))? I added it below my last dense layer of 80 and I got another error message: 'TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable'

Comment: My mistake, it appears you should use model.add(tf.keras.layers.Reshape((-1,))). See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46541974/keras-typeerror-int-object-is-not-iterable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get your code working with some changes, it appears the error was occuring due to your use of "sparse_categorical_crossentropy." I don't know why you were using this as your classes don't seem to be exclusive, ie. your have a score of '1' at several rows in your tftest.csv for each entry. Also, you shouldn't normalize your labels. I made these changes:

```
x_train = num_converter_flatten(distribution_train)
y_train = num_converter_flatten(probs_train)

x_train = tf.keras.utils.normalize(x_train, axis=1)
y_train = np.array(y_train)#tf.keras.utils.normalize(y_train, axis=1)
```

and further down:

```
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(80, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Again, since your classes don't seem to be exclusive, you shouldn't use the softmax activation.

But since the code now works, you can work on optimizing things (it didn't seem to train well for the 5 epochs I ran it for).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out later and tell you how it went. Yup it's more of less my project...to condense equations and generate a probability matrix to see how much infomation is lost during that condensation process. But thanks for taking the time to help me! I greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Don't be disheartened! Analyse why. I tried some simple things before (like using an RMSE loss function, definitely increasing the number of epochs, and changing the architecture of the model) to improve the network and it seemed to help. This is the challenging part of ML, but understanding the problem and what you're trying to do it a core tenet. I might also recommend using a simpler system like a decision tree classifier if you feel your data is too small for a deep learning problem.